# How generate hibernate.cfg.xml with maven (hibernate3-maven-plugin)?

Tags: hibernate, maven, maven-plugin

I'm newbie with Maven. I need generate a hibernate.cfg.xml more I don't idea about this. In this link (http://mojohaus.org/hibernate3-maven-plugin)  I don't understand how configures. Somebody can help-me?
Thanks a advance.

Comment: I'd use a standard `persistence.xml` instead of the proprietary `hibernate.cfg.xml` whenever possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorry for delay, but I have a solution.
I have two archive, being: pom.xml and build.bat (build.xml).
The build.xml has my configuration for generate the mapping of the hibernate.

I got it run (build.xml) through of pom.xml with below command (something similar the example of the Gilberto Torrezan).

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
  <executions>
     <execution>
     <phase>generate-sources</phase>
     <goals> 
            <goal>exec</goal>
     </goals>
     </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
     <executable>ant/build_hibernate.bat</executable>
   </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [plugin you mentioned](http://mojo.codehaus.org/hibernate3-maven-plugin/hbm2cfgxml-mojo.html), you can set these properties in you pom.xml:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goal>hbm2cfgxml</goal>
            </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

The plugin will be executed after the `compile` phase.